# how to convert my angular form structure to capture pre-filled data from an API (reactive form)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am making a form to update user details on Angular, I wish to make some changes to the existing structure here such that the data gets pre-filled on all input fields as the user loads the page.

component.ts file

```
 constructor(
private fb:FormBuilder,
private router: Router,
private apiService:ApiService,
private activRouter:ActivatedRoute,
) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
const urlParam=this.activRouter.snapshot.params
for(let x in urlParam){
  this.id=urlParam[x]  //for capturing individual id of user to be edited from url
}

this.apiService.getRequest(`user/details/${this.id}`).subscribe((res:any)=>{
  this.formFieldData=res["data"] //to capture the data values to be pre-filled in my form from the backend
})
 this.editUserForm=this.fb.group({
 "name":[`${this.formFieldData["name"]}`,Validators.required],
 "address":[`${this.formFieldData["address"]}`,Validators.required]
   ......
   ......
   ......
})
```

HTML code form sample

```
<form [formGroup]="editUserForm" (submit)="editUserDetails()">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name"> Name</label>
   <input type="text" #name class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" formControlName="name">
   <app-validation [control]="editUserForm.controls.name"></app-validation>
    </div>
```

app-validation component:

```
<div class="form-text error" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>
```

I just want to make some changes to the formbuilder structure in my ts file so that I can load the data to be pre-filled in html template in a more dynamic way

Comment: You need create the form **inside** subscribe function. Rememeber that when you call to your service is a "async" call. You don't know when the call is finished. BTW take a look to the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service) if was necesary not only ask about `activRouter.snapshot.params` else subscribe to `this.route.paramMap`

Answer (score 0):

As api request is an async operation so before having the data inside this.formFieldData, your form has been intiated. I've refactore your code, ask to try it,

```
constructor(
private fb:FormBuilder,
private router: Router,
private apiService:ApiService,
private activRouter:ActivatedRoute,
) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
const urlParam=this.activRouter.snapshot.params
for(let x in urlParam){
  this.id=urlParam[x]  //for capturing individual id of user to be edited from url
this.apiService.getRequest(`user/details/${this.id}`).subscribe((res:any)=>{
  this.formFieldData=res["data"] //to capture the data values to be pre-filled in my form from the backend
})
 this.editUserForm=this.fb.group({
 "name":[`${this.formFieldData["name"]}`,Validators.required],
 "address":[`${this.formFieldData["address"]}`,Validators.required]
   ......
   ......
   ......
})
}
}
```